# Generate series not later than today

Tags: postgresql

Is there a way to generate dates not later than today?

```
generate_series('2019-09-01'::timestamp, '2020-09-25'::timestamp, interval '1 day')
```

If today's day is `2020-09-23` I wouldn't like to get dates `2020-09-24` and `2020-09-25`

Both dates are dynamic, it depends on user input. Left date could be any. Right date could be any, but not later than today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=ce5ca71e6f9568f56ba7d92f80f75fba)

Using `least()` gives the smaller value. So if you take your end date and this exceeds the `CURRENT_DATE`, the `CURRENT_DATE` becomes smallest value and will be taken:

```
generate_series(
    '2019-09-01'::timestamp, 
    least(current_date, '2019-09-25'), 
    interval '1 day'
)
```

Comment: no, those two dates are dynamic, it could be any date, but shouldn't be later than today

Comment: Ah, ok. Changed the answer

Comment: yeah, this is exactly what i was looking for, thanks